# How can I automatically update the Javadoc when changing the method signature in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse IDE for my Java Project.

I have one problem. I have the methods in my project which have the javadoc comments like as follows:

```
/**
 * Retruns the string representation of a input stream
 * @param in
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String getStringFromInputStream (InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
        out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Now I want to know that Is there any way by which whenever if I make changes in my method's signature, those changes reflect in the javadoc automatically.

Comment: Might be good to retitle this.  There's no problem with javadoc as the title claims.  Maybe something along the lines of "Refactoring from JavaDoc changes in Eclipse".  I don't think you can do this without writing a plugin, btw.

Comment: **This is still open to answer !!!!**.
All answer refer to refactor option. But what if I added a new param or deleted a param from method signature. In that case, how to update the javadoc?

Comment: Guys check my answer for a workaround !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Atl+Shift+R` and change

Comment: Only works with parameter names. Signature changes also include adding/removing parameters, changing the throws clause, etc.

Comment: Technically, this is just the command [for `Refactor` > `Rename`](http://www.n0sl33p.org/dev/eclipse_keys.html).

Answer (score 13):

Eclipse provides fairly good options to ensure the correctness of javadoc besides the *Rename* refactor JesperE mentioned:

- The *Change method signature* refactor operation also modifies javadoc (add/remove necessary tags). You should use this one or *Rename* to modify code which are already in use.
- If you activate *Add Javadoc tags* on *Preferences/Java/Editor/Typing* page then Eclipse generates the correct javadoc stub after typing `/**` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> before a method.

You can also set compiler options to check javadoc missing tags on *Preferences/Java/Compiler/Javadoc*. In this case you get warnings from the compiler on missing/extra tags and you have quickfix (<kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>) for fixing them. It is a good option to ensure the correctness of existing javadocs in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any way to automatically sync the Javadoc header, but if you rename a parameter using `Ctrl-1` + `Rename in file`, the Javadoc header is appropriately renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Refactoring with the "Update references" option is not sufficient. You need to ensure that "Process Javadoc comments" is checked in Window->Preferences, Java->Compiler->Javadoc. Tweak the preference page like you prefer and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just press ALT+SHIFT+j on the method name and delete the extra lines:

BEFORE:

```
/**
 * Copies all the details from the passed template into the passed new
 * header.
 *
 * @param pNewHeader
 */
private void doCopy(int pNewHeader, int pTemplate) {
```

AFTER:

```
/**
 * Copies all the details from the passed template into the passed new
 * header.
 *
 * @param pNewHeader   << DELETE
 */                    << DELETE
/**                    << DELETE
 * @param pNewHeader
 * @param pTemplate
 */
private void doCopy(int pNewHeader, int pTemplate) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have commented the scenario, in which refactor won't work

> > All answer refer to refactor option. But what if I added a new param or deleted a param from method signature. In that case, how to update the javadoc?

There is a workaround I found, but yes it's still not a automated process and is not good for large number of changes.

The workaround is to,
1. remove the javadoc comment and make it plain comment i.e. update the `/**' and change it to just`/*'.
2. Now once again just above the method signature/declaration enter `/**` and press enter. It would re-populate the updated params and return info. Now just move the description lines from the older comment to the new.
3. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrows for achieving this.
4. Done delete the old javadoc comment after it's copied in correct place.

Comment: _"But what if I added a new param or deleted a param from method signature. In that case, how to update the javadoc?"_ — Csaba_H's answer addresses this; you use _Refactor_ > _Change Method Signature..._ and it will add and/or remove the param(s) on both the method signature _and_ the javadoc.