# How to set JavaDoc to update automatically when I change the method signature in Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there a way to make JavaDoc update and add extra corresponding tags when I for example add return value to a method which was void before. This way JavaDoc will be updated as we change the code.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260359/how-can-i-automatically-update-the-javadoc-when-changing-the-method-signature-in) asked 6 years ago for eclipse but no answer to that yet. As it says there too in the comments it's not about refactoring a name.

```
 /**
 * Some explanation about method.
 *
 * @return (I want this tag to be added automatically after I add return type "int" to method)
 */
private int ourMethod() {
    int price = quantity * 5;
    return price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 2016.2, there is no feature in IntelliJ IDEA that would add a `@return` tag for a method when you change its return type.

For parameters, if you use the "Change signature" refactoring, it will add `@param` tags for new parameters, delete them for parameters you remove, and update them for parameters you rename. The Rename refactoring will also rename `@param` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I found this also can be useful.

["Fix doc comment"](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/09/fix-doc-comment-action-is-available/) is a simple useful way to automatically add JavaDoc for a method. Assign a shortcut in Keymap setting (alt+shift+0 for example) and hit it when the caret is inside a method, it also updates the current JavaDoc according to changes you've just made and moves the caret inside JavaDoc to make things easier.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+A, with the caret somewhere within a class, method, function, or field, which should be documented, and enter the action name Fix Doc String.

Comment: @okwap thaks for that! it's "Fix Doc Comment" anyway, just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no automatic method to add the JavaDoc by changing it's method. However, you can do it by start typing `/**` at the top of the method and press enter. The parameters as well as the return are inserted automaticly then.